# Python: Programming a game GUI

Tags: gui, python

I'm looking for some suggestion on books or tutorials to make a game GUI with inventory management, map , stats... in python, as this is the only language I know a bit of so far. I want to design it to feel like a modern game GUI, have taken a look at tkinter, but the resulting GUI/UI looks very "old". Im not going to make a game or something, but just want to make the GUI for excitement and learning.

My idea is to make images in Gimp or something similar. "Plot" the image like I would do to a point or curve in matplotlib, but with another library and define areas of the images as buttons that I can interact with with mouse and keyboard. I am fully aware that the aforementioned idea may be very bad, but I hope that it gives and idea of what I want to achieve.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Suggestion on books, tutorials and which packages to use for python to make a game GUI . Let's say as an example I want to mimic the pip boy menu in Fallout 4. How would you do that using python? Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Stack Exchange excels where there's a specific issue that you're trying to solve. If you could reformat the question so that there's a specific question, and a correct answer you'd have a lot more luck with results.

Comment: The issue with your question is that you are asking on how to get started, and seem to be rambling different topics of discussion.  This site requires a defined question.  You might be better off posting this in a discussion based forum such as gamedev.net, or possible reddit.com/r/gamedev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some help/suggestions, it would be a good idea to give more details.

Is this a 2D Game, a 3D Game? What Game Engine are you using, or What graphics library are you using?

tkinter is a desktop GUI toolkit. These are generally not used for games. For games you generally want to render the images and ui elements with a library specifically meant for games/your engine or directly through your graphics library.

Most of the time, the UI is added through a special set of classes/calls in the game engine you are using.

If you are not using a game engine generally it works like this.

First you draw your scene, the main game render. Then, if your game is 3D, you switch to a 2D rendering context on top of the 3D and then draw your ui much like you would any other game object.

If you need suggestions for python game engines to start with, I know of a couple that seem fairly popular. ( I have never used them myself though. ) Their sites should have starter tutorials to walk you through things such as making a simple game and UI.

2D: pyGame: http://www.pygame.org/
3D: Panda3d: https://www.panda3d.org/